# How to use servicestack typed client?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, typed

Basically we have a redis instance and we would like to Save and Get all items from a Redis List.

We can Save it but when we tried to get the list

```
var redis = redisclient.As<MyModel>();
string key = "myredislistkey";
List<MyModel> mylist = redis.GetAllItemsFromList(key);
```

I know this is wrong but why? And how to properly use Typed client to Getallitems using a redis key(or so called listid)?

Official usage is

```
List<T> GetAllItemsFromList(IRedisList<T> fromList);
```

But if I already have fromList, why would I trying to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a reference to a Typed List (i.e. `IRedisList<T>`) with:

```
var redisModels = redisClient.As<MyModel>().List["myredislistkey"];
```

`IRedisList<T>` is just an adapter that implements the .NET `IList<T>` interface over a remote redis LIST, i.e. it doesn't contain any elements itself, you would use it to interface with this list, e.g:

Add Items to it with:

```
redisModels.Add(new MyModel { ... });
redisModels.AddRange(new[] { new MyModel { ... }, new MyModel { ... } });
```

And get all elements with:

```
var allModels = redisModels.GetAll();
```

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I'm hoping for. And btw, if you could give me a doc site link for typed redis client and normal redis client I can reference them in the future. Right now all I can find is this https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/IRedisTypedClient

Comment: @shawhu docs are kind of scattered everywhere, they were originally on [docs.servicestack.net](http://docs.servicestack.net) but a lot of it is on StackOverflow. Although [from this release](https://servicestack.net/release-notes) we've started adding more docs to the project repo which we'll continue to add. Feel free to keep asking questions here in the meantime if you hit blockers.

Comment: Well then, I'll have to ask for help more in here. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. One thing: I think it should be `redisClient.As<MyModel>().Lists["myredislistkey"];` and not `redisClient.As<MyModel>().List["myredislistkey"];`, there is an 's' missing...